# Scala convert Map$ to Map

Tags: scala, jackson

I have an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$ cannot
>   be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

which i'm getting in this part of code:

```
 val iterator = new CsvMapper()
  .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
  .readerFor(Map.getClass).`with`(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader()).readValues(reader)

while (iterator.hasNext) {
  println(iterator.next.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])
}
```

So, are there any options to avoid this issue, because this:

```
val iterator = new CsvMapper()
  .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
  .readerFor(Map[String,String].getClass).`with`(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader()).readValues(reader)
```

doesn't help, because I get

```
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Map.getClass` is the class of Map companion object. You probably want `classOf[Map[_, _]]`

Comment: Is not there anything after the `$` sign? Just because `$` in Java separates the inner classes from the main class...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto : The scala compiler just adds a single dollar sign at the end of the class name for `object`s (so `object MyObject` gets compiled to a class named `MyObject$`).

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov Thank you, I forgot about classOf function .Now I recieve `Can not construct instance of scala.collection.immutable.Map: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

Comment: Last error `Can not construct instance of scala.collection.immutable.Map: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information` was resoleved by using 
`classOf[java.util.Map[_,_]]`.

Comment: are you using jackson?

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the earlier comments, in general you need `classOf[X[_,_]]` rather than `X.getClass` or `X[A, B].getClass` for a class that takes two generic types. (`instance.getClass` retrieves the class of the associated `instance`; `classOf[X]` does the same for some type `X` when an instance isn't available. Since `Map` is an *object* and objects are also instances, it retrieves the class type of the object `Map` - the `Map` *trait*'s companion.)

However, a second problem here is that `scala.collection.immutable.Map` is *abstract* (it's actually a trait), and so it cannot be instantiated *as-is*. (If you look at the type of *Scala* `Map` instances created via the companion's `apply` method, you'll see that they're actually instances of classes such as `Map.EmptyMap` or `Map.Map1`, etc.) As a consequence, that's why your modified code still produced an error.

However, the ultimate problem here is that you required - as you mentioned - a *Java* `java.util.Map` and not a *Scala* `scala.collections.immutable.Map` (which is what you'll get by default it you just type `Map` in a *Scala* program). Just one more thing to watch out for when converting *Java* code examples to *Scala*. ;-)